# Sample size requirements for evaluating a many-class classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistical-power, model-evaluation, many-categories

I am working on defining the requirements for a test/evaluation dataset for a many-class classifier (n_classes ~ 1,000), and am working to address concerns about ensuring the statistical power of the classifier.

At a high level, I can frame the problem as a binary classification problem and extend the sample size requirements to the rest of the data (e.g. if the req is 30 samples for the binary problem, I can require 30*1,000 total observations).  What other methods can I use to define requirements for the sample size required for reliable evaluation?

Additionally, how can I show that a classifier which is able to predict the correct class out of many other classes - even if just for a few cases - inherently has strong power due to low prob of selecting at random? Shouldn't this also strongly impact the required sample size for evaluation? such that we would need a much smaller sample size to prove its predictive power.  Or what is another way to frame this problem and estimate the number of samples needed per class to evaluate the classifier?

Assume that the classifier is already built, and has been trained on sufficient data.

Edit: and assume that the input data is very high-dimensional